# Can't connect to Cloud Firestore Database on Cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-firestore, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to build an app with Cordova where I want to connect a Google Cloud Firestore database.

I use the [Cordova Firestore Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firestore) and followed the installation steps (add google-services.json, install dependencies etc.). To learn how the plugin is used, I build my app and connect it with Chrome DevTools to play around with the console.

When I try to get data from firestore via console like explained in the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firestore#example) of the plugin, I always get the following error:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

I googled on that and found hints to change the version of `com.google.gms:google-services` to minimum `3.1.1`.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I've been fiddling around with the same problem for a while.

Comment: @Roope Not yet. But I haven‘t worked on this for a while. When I continue working on this and find a solution, I‘ll let you know. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I faced the same issue and found a solution here:

https://github.com/ReallySmallSoftware/cordova-plugin-firestore/issues/11#issuecomment-453435050

By commenting out config{}: that makes both browser and android platforms work (not tested on iOS yet)

Here the updated example:

https://github.com/ReallySmallSoftware/cordova-plugin-firestore/issues/13#issuecomment-467531402

```
var options = {
    "datePrefix": '__DATE:',
    "fieldValueDelete": "__DELETE",
    "fieldValueServerTimestamp" : "__SERVERTIMESTAMP",
    "persist": true,
//  "config" : {}
};
```

Comment: I also found a similar solution a few days ago. I also deleted the config line, because I'm using the google-services.json file.

I think you can also set _apiKey_, _authDomain_ and _projectId_ inside the options directly instead of inside the config to get this working.